# How to create different Views pages for different taxonomy vocabularies?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have two vocabularies that require two different taxonomy view pages. For example, I have vertebrates with terms fish, cats and snakes and invertebrates with sea cucumbers, spiders and snails. I would like to create a different view for each. Can I configure Path Auto to create separate URLs passing the vocabulary term ID as an argument? If so then how do I change the link of the Term found in the Term Reference field of the node view to point to these pages? I'm thinking about installing the [Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) but would rather leave out an extra module if it's just a matter of configuring a Views argument correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Taxonomy Views Switcher](http://drupal.org/sandbox/simg/1106944) does the trick. It does something clever. If the default view page path is 'taxonomy/term/%' it will walk through the paths of the. If the vid of the term is 3 it will associate the term with the view that has vid/3 in the path and will when taxonomy/term/% is called pass it -- the second view -- the argument of the term ID. Since this is a separate view it can have any field, sort, filter or display plugin.

Now I need to trigger contexts based on views that are triggered.

Comment: Were you able to find out more about this? Did taxonomy Views switcher meet your needs? I m having the same issue currently and I too would prefer to configure views differently or use a PHP snippet to avoid another module.